# How does one delete millions of documents in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

We have searched for and tried several ways to delete documents in Marklogic and have not found a reliable way to delete millions of them without having to check if they have in fact been deleted.  The way we found that will delete the whole collection is by using the `xdmp:collection-delete` function but it is REALLY slow.  The quickest way we've found is to use the following XQuery.  But we must run the XQuery, wait for it to finish, check if there are any documents left in the collection, and repeat a few more times until everything has been deleted.

We are by no means proficient at coding XQuery so we may be missing something.

How does the Marklogic community delete millions of documents quickly and reliably?

Here is the XQuery we use:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $page-size := 1000
let $uris := cts:uris('', (), cts:collection-query('OurCollection'))
let $pages := (count($uris) idiv $page-size) + 1
return 
  for $page in (1 to $pages)
  let $start := (($page - 1) * $page-size) + 1 
  let $end := $page * $page-size
  let $uris := subsequence($uris, $start, $end)
  return
    xdmp:spawn-function(function(){
      for $uri in $uris
      return
        xdmp:document-delete($uri)
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spawning chunks of deletes like you have shown is one way, and the easiest without any external tools. You could bump up the task server threads to get some more concurrency, but it could still take a while.

Another very common means of performing bulk activities, such as deleting millions of docs, is to run a [CoRB](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2) job. You can control the number of threads that the job uses for concurrent requests, and send the request across to all E-node using either a load balancer or [CoRBs multi-host load balancing feature](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#load-balancing-and-failover-with-multiple-hosts).

https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/best-practices-for-improving-the-performance-of-large-collections-deletes

Comment: The ML server does not queue the spawned deletes to execute when threads are free.  Is that correct?  I just want to settle whether we need to abandon the spawned document deletes and go with a directory delete.

Comment: You can spawn faster than they will execute, and they will queue. You can watch the Task Server status and see it drain. The risk of queued tasks is that if the server restarts, those tasks are lost and won't resume. Of course, for something like a delete-all, you can just re-run that query and re-spawn the remaining deletes, so not as much of a concern. The primary limitation though is that spawned work only goes to that one server's task server, so you are not taking full advantage of the cluster the way that a CoRB job could to blast those docs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have downloaded CoRB last week and skimmed through the guide.  Seemed like it was pretty complicated.  I'll have to start from the beginning and read it.  Everyone is so Pro-CoRB

Comment: Is there a CoRB training class online anywhere?  I think that would be really handy for a few folks.

Comment: Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wf9FT2O3drs the GitHub wiki has some helpful pages https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki and there are examples https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/tree/master/examples